# How to wait all task when I not always I run some of them?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I wanted to run some code in parallel using tasks, but some of this parallel code sometimes I have to run and sometimes not. Depends of some conditions. So I was thinking in a code like that:

```
Task myTsk01 = null;
Task myTsk02 = null;
Task myTsk03 = null;

if(condition01 true) myTask01 = Task.Run(() => myCode01);
if(condition02 true) myTask02 = Task.Run(() => myCode02);
if(condition03 true) myTask03 = Task.Run(() => myCode03);

Task.WaitAll(myTsk01, myTsk02, myTsk03);
```

However, with this code, I get an error because sometimes at least one task is null.

So I Have tried another option:

```
Task myTsk01 = null;
 Task myTsk02 = null;
 Task myTsk03 = null;
 List<Task> myLstTasks = new List<Tasks>();
 if(condition01 true) miLstTasks.Add(Task.Run(() => myCode01));
 if(condition02 true) miLstTasks.Add(Task.Run(() => myCode02));
 if(condition03 true) miLstTasks.Add(Task.Run(() => myCode03));

 Task.WaitAll(myLstTasks.ToArray());
```

In this case I can get the same error if the list is empty because all conditions are false.

So my last solution is:

```
 Task myTsk01 = null;
 Task myTsk02 = null;
 Task myTsk03 = null;
 List<Task> myLstTasks = new List<Tasks>();
 if(condition01 true) miLstTasks.Add(Task.Run(() => myCode01));
 if(condition02 true) miLstTasks.Add(Task.Run(() => myCode02));
 if(condition03 true) miLstTasks.Add(Task.Run(() => myCode03));

 if(myListTsk.Count > 0) Task.WaitAll(myLstTasks.ToArray());
```

This solution works, but I think that to use an if to check if the list is empty is not the best way to do it, because I guess that run tasks according to a condition and wait all of them it has to be a common case. But I don't be able to find a better solution.

So I would like to know if this is the best solution or if there are any other that is better.

Thanks.

Comment: Nothing much better than your last solution. Of course, without the null task variables you never use...

Comment: The last one seems fine to me.

Comment: I don't see any problems with the second option. ToArray() on an empty list should return an empty array, and Task.WaitAll() should just return immediately in that case.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your second solution, see [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BYgSSH) for example.

Comment: And although I wouldn't do it here [Task.FromResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194922(v=vs.110).aspx) lets you create an already completed task which could be used in a place where you need a task, can't pass `null`, but don't actually have a task to run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would work just fine, without having to reference the Tasks individually:

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Tasks>();

if(condition01) 
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => myCode01));
if(condition02)
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => myCode02));
if(condition03) 
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => myCode03));

Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

There's also no need to check whether `tasks` is empty.